# Interpretation of drop.test output in R

Tags: r, regression, interpretation, robust

Could someone clarify the purpose of the *drop in dispersion test* (`drop.test`) in the [Rfit package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rfit/index.html) in R? I think that it shows the difference in explanatory power between the full and reduced models in linear regression. I don't understand where 'dispersion' comes into it.

The output for the drop in dispersion test of my models is:

```
F-statistic = 1.90451, p-value = 0.14911...
```

How would I interpret this other than not being significant?

NB. to clarify, I do not need help with the code, just the interpretation of the test output results!

Comment: This is probably best gotten from the documentation ([?drop.test](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/library/Rfit/html/drop.test.html), [?rfit](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/library/Rfit/html/rfit.html)). Can you make the content here more statistical & less about understanding R code?

Comment: Hi gung, i've had a look at those links previously, I'm just not sure what they mean by 'dispersion' ? And could you clarify what you mean by 'more statistical'? Thanks!

Comment: Questions about R code are off topic here. If this is a question about statistics, rather than a question about how to get something done in R or how it works, the question will stay open (& presumably get an answer). If this is a question about how some R function works, it will probably be closed.

Comment: I've been directed here from Stats Exchange already! I've run the test already, so it's not a question about the programming language - I am just asking for an explanation of the statistical test itself and how to interpret the output values.. Any help would be appreciated as I'm struggling to find clear help with Rfit outputs online.

Comment: OK, I guess this is more of a statistics question than a 'how does R work' question. You should delete your [SO] question, though. Cross-posting is against SE policy.